# Cannot start multiple python processes at the same time

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to run a multiprocessing program but for some reason the processes do not start at the same time, they wait for the other one to finish. Below is a piece of the code and some outputs. Could you please advise?
I am running python 2.7 on windows 10 but i tested on python 3.5 Ubuntu as well with the same results.

Even though both processes are running the same function it doesn't matter for me which one finishes first because their results are not tied, I just want to use better the CPU

```
import multiprocessing
import time
import os

def function(x):
    seq1 = x
    index = 1
    match = False
    t = time.time()

    while match == False:
.........................
       if k==6 :
          match = True

       index = index + 1

def Main():
    x1=raw_input("Please enter first sequence: ")
    seq1=[]
    seq1 = x1.split(",")

    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=function(seq1),)
    p1.start()
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=function(seq1),)
    p2.start()

Main()
```

Output(I have to wait until P1 finishes and then P2 starts):
P1 started
process id: 4520
Match found in: 30401191 tries
('done by P1 in: ', 1072.0950000286102)
P2 started
process id: 4520
Match found in: 8665524 tries
('done by P2 in: ', 298.375)

Comment: python excutes its programs synchronously. So you can not execute two functions at the same time. but you can achieve it by using [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#module-threading) _italic_ **bold** `threading` and multiprocessing

Comment: `k` is not defined....

Comment: If you're on Windows you need to not call `Main` at the top level of the module. See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#windows).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are misusing the [`multiprocessing.Process`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiprocessing#multiprocessing.Process) class interface. You need to pass the function as a target and the arguments in a list.

Your logic is calling the function and passing its results as a target to the process.

```
p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=function, args=(seq1,))
p1.start()
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=function, args=(seq1,))
p2.start()
```